Python - Define a function with changing argument and insert that function into another function
Let's say I have two functions where one depends on the other. I need to now put the first function inside the second function, and then integrate.
I've attempted it as below but it doesn't work, giving the error: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'function'
import scipy as sp
from scipy import integrate

def q_vals():
    return lambda x: x / (0.3 * 0.7 * np.exp(- 0.224))
                                                    
def transfer_fn_sq(q = q_vals()):
    return lambda x: (np.log(1 + 2.34 * q) * (1 + 3.89 * q)

y = scipy.integrate.quad.(transfer_fn_sq, 1, np.inf)

I need to do it this way as I have multiple functions with longer expressions which are dependent on the previous function, so I can't simply type the whole expression out into the integral function.
Thanks

Why are you using all those lambdas?
    def q_vals(x):
        return x / (0.3 * 0.7 * np.exp(- 0.224))

    def transfer_fn_sq(x):
        q = q_vals(x)
        return np.log(1 + 2.34 * q) * (1 + 3.89 * q)

    return sp.integrate.quad(transfer_fn_sq, 1, np.inf)

